# printer error Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf

Tags: printing

I tried to install Canon LBP 2900B printer on Ubuntu 18.04.
I followed instructions from an answer to a similar question. 
It is as follows -

Download Linux capt driver version 2.71

Extract it into download folder and opened the folder for 64 bit, as my installation is 64 bit:

downloads → linux capt... → 64 bit driver → debian

After that double click on the files, the Ubuntu software center opens and asks to install it. Install both the files one by one, second one first.

Install the following additional packages from the Ubuntu software center: portreserve, gsfonts, gsfonts-other, gsfonts-X11.

Restart the printer

```
service cups restart
```

Add your printer and start the printer daemon:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E 
sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
sudo service ccpd start
sudo service ccpd status
```

Check the function of the printer:

```
captstatusui -P LBP2900
```

this will popup a new window. If the message is "Ready to print", you are done. If the message is error of no printer connected etc., restart the operating system and repeat the steps five to seven, and it will start.

Up to last step everything was perfect. On last step i.e.

7. Check the function of the printer:

captstatusui -P LBP2900

I get following error.

printer error

Check the DevicePath of `/etc/ccpd.conf`

I tried to ask about it to the person who answered, but I am unable to post a comment as I don't have 50 points as per the site's policy.

Please help me proceed further through this 7th step. I think I am closer to make my printer work on Ubuntu.

Comment: you should be using version 2.71 from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html that was issued 15th May 2017; and you probably should use /dev/usb/lp1 as the DevicePath line in ccpd.conf just says `DevicePath /dev/usb/lp1` or `DevicePath /dev/usb/lp0` as is appropriate

Comment: Hey PDC, you are here again to help. Thanks! Actually I downloaded drivers 2.71 only, but I copy pasted the answer from other question without editing it. Now I changed the question. Also previously in question it was 32 bit system, as mine is 64 so I changed it too in the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I didn't understand your instructions about device path. Should I edit ccpd.conf file? If yes then also guide me regarding permission issue as I cannot directly edit files in /etc folder as that file is located in that folder.

Comment: no; just telling you the error is it can't find the printer; see other post for another suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Check the DevicePath of /etc/ccpd.conf
```

comes from missing 32-bit libxml2 library. Install this library to get rid of this error. That's probably not the last action to do to get your CAPT printer running, but at least the config file would be read.

On Ubuntu 18.04 x64 i used this command to install 32bit libxml2.so

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
```

There may be some other libraries missing also. To check this, run `ldd` on `/usr/bin/capt*` executables, for instance, `ldd /usr/bin/captmon2`. Check the list of libraries for `not found` marks and find a way to install them.

Comment: In addition, I had to install libpopt0:i386 (and you'll need to add i386 architecture like sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, sudo apt update).